# How do I get points on a curve in PHP with log()?

Tags: php, math, logging, points, curve

I have a graph I am trying to replicate:

[image: GAP Graph]

I have the following PHP code:

```
 $sale_price = 25000;
 $future_val = 5000;
 $term = 60;

 $x = $sale_price / $future_val;
 $pts = array();
 $pts[] = array($x,0);
 for ($i=1; $i<=$term; $i++) {
   $y = log($x+0.4)+2.5;
   $pts[] = array($i,$y);
   echo $y . " <br>\n";
 }
```

How do I make the code work to give me the points along the lower line (between the yellow and blue areas)?  It doesn't need to be exact, just somewhat close.

The formula is:

```
-ln(x+.4)+2.5
```

I got that by using the Online Function Grapher at [http://www.livephysics.com/](http://www.livephysics.com/ptools/online-function-grapher.php?ymin=0&xmin=0&ymax=5&xmax=5&f1=-ln%28x%2B.4%29%2B2.5&f2=&f3=)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What actually issues you have already experienced?

Comment: You should describe what isn't working in your current code.

Comment: For one thing, the formula in the code doesn't match the one given.  `$y = -log($x + .4) + 2.5`  (or, less weirdly, `$y = 2.5 - log($x + .4)`) would work better.

Comment: I don't know.  I'm not very good at putting formulas together.  I can code them if they're decent, but this is a raw math function and ... I'm having a brainfart converting it to code.

Comment: As far as what isn't working - the loop does nothing to change the value because log($x + .4) is always the same.  I'm not changing $x at any point and not sure how it needs to be done in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$y = log($x+0.4)+2.5;
```

Should be

```
$y = 2.5 - log($i + .4)
```

X values are the loan term, which you have assigned to `$i`.

Also, why is your loan term max value 60? Did you convert years to months? Make sure the equation is changed accordingly.

Not quite sure of the validity of your equation though. Check out graph: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y+%3D+ln%28x+%2B+0.4%29+%2B+2.5

Comment: +1: For WolframAlpha. Oh, and the rest of your answer looks legit. ;)

Comment: And the term is in months, even tho the graph shows years.  That gives more granularity in points and term can be non-whole years (39 mo).  And X should be the factor of sale price to final value to give a starting point.  X cannot be the term because then it's just decrementing by gibberish values, isn't it?  Maybe I'm wrong.  Probably.  I hate logarithmic algebra!

Comment: That above comment did it.  Thanks!

Comment: Alright then. But check this function out [link](http://www.livephysics.com/ptools/online-function-grapher.php?ymin=0&xmin=0&ymax=27000&xmax=60&f1=-1700*sqrt(5%2F3)*sqrt(x)+25000&f2=&f3=) with X = term and Y = $ EDIT: the multiplication signs disappear in the link...

Comment: Thanks, domesterr - you got me going in the right direction.  This doesn't have to be exact.  That graph is just a generalization to represent the values and that's all I need at this point.  Thanks again!